# Adding malt powder to a conventional brown bread machine recipe

Tags: bread

I'm English by birth and miss the 'old fashioned' style Granary bread of my youth. I use a breadmaker and have 'fine-tuned' recipes to produce something approaching the bread I miss: I add small quantities of several types of grains and pumpkin and sunflower seeds.

Now, however, I've purchased a quantity of malt powder in the hope that I can reproduce the malty flavour of 'real' Granary bread.

Question: How much malt powder should I add to my recipe?

Answer (score 1):

As it's really hard for us here on Seasoned Advice to quantify a memory from your youth, please **experiment using the binary empirical method:**

1. start with one spoon ¹
2. if that's not malty enough for you, double the dose
3. keep doubling the dose until it's too malty
4. then go halfway in-between the too low dose and the too high dose (E.G. if 4 is not enough and 8 is too much, take 6)
5. keep on halving until you get it *just right* (E.G in the above example: 5, 4.5, 4.25, 4.125, ...)

If you get it just right, *dream of childhood memories...*

### :-)

<sub>¹ Obviously "spoon" is a non-SI unit and can be a coffee spoon, tea spoon, table spoon or even a ladle depending on the size of the bread and how malty your memory of the Granary bread reallly is...</sub>  **;-)**